# asp Default document not working on IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, default-document

I have a classic asp application inside a .NET 4.0 application. I have set the default document to *login.asp*, but it does not automatically redirect to it. The entire application functions fine though and even displays the login.asp correctly if I browse to it.

The default document section in web.config is as below:

```
<defaultDocument>
    <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="login.asp" />
        <add value="index.html" />
        <add value="default.aspx" />
        <add value="Default.htm" />
        <add value="Default.asp" />
        <add value="index.htm" />
        <add value="iisstart.htm" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

I have looked at other similar questions on this site but were not of much help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found the issue was because the asp application was assigned to an app pool in classic mode using .NET Framework 4.0.

Once I changed the app pool to use .NET Framework 2.0 (with managed pipeline in classic mode), the default document started to work too!

Comment: Are you sure the new app pool is in Classic mode? I forgot that `system.webServer` section only works in Integrated mode.

Comment: Yes, I had to make it classic mode to get the asp application to work.

Comment: You saved my week! Nothing about the site was changed, but a Windows update must have made something as the site would start with my custom `DefaultPage`. I didn't change the pipeline mode, but setting the .NET version to 2.0.x made the site load again.

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure you have Read/Write [Feature Delegation enabled](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/155/an-overview-of-feature-delegation-in-iis-70/#02) for Default Document:
   [image: 1.jpg]
2. DefaultDocument does not redirect to the file (i.e. URL is not changed). It acts similar to `Server.Transfer` function — executes the file when root URL (http://sitename/) is requested. Probably, your login.asp executed but it has instructions to redirect logged-in users to a different page, or display the different content to them.
3. Make sure the response is not cached. Clear cache and cookies and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear instructions. I finally found the issue was because the asp application was assigned to an app pool in classic mode using .net framework 4.0. Once I changed this to use .net 2.0, the default document started to work too!

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem today with a brand new asp.net site deployed to Azure. I tried messing with IIS and my web.config included

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
    <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Index.html" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Turns out my problem was that the File > New Project wizard uses .NET 4.5.2 by default, and that isn't fully supported yet in Azure. I recompiled using .NET 4.5 as the target and everything works now!